How to import the sole symbol \vBar without the whole fdsymbol package
I would like to import the single symbol \vBar from the package fdsymbol.
I know I have to use a command like \DeclareFontFamily and \DeclareMathSymbol but don't know which abbreviations and settings to plug in for these commands.
Any help would be much appreciated.

The general solution is shown in the answers to: Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font
In your case reading fdsymbol.sty could be a bit more complicated. Something like:
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolC}{m}{n}{
    <-7.1> s * FdSymbolC-Book
    <7.1-> s * FdSymbolC-Book
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows}{U}{FdSymbolC}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vBar}{\mathrel}{arrows}{245}
\begin{document}
$\vBar$
\end{document}


should IMHO do it. I've found it, starting from the definition of \vBar in fdsymbol.sty and expanding the definition step by step.
The most time-consuming part was tracking the \@tempcnta counter. ;-)
No, it wasn't, I've just edited a renamed copy of fdsymbol.sty and changed the definition of \fdsy@@DeclareSymbol from
\newcommand\fdsy@@DeclareSymbol[4]{\DeclareMathSymbol{#2}{#3}{#4}{#1}}

into
\newcommand\fdsy@@DeclareSymbol[4]{%
  \typeout{\unexpanded{\DeclareMathSymbol{#2}{#3}{#4}{#1}}}%
  \DeclareMathSymbol{#2}{#3}{#4}{#1}%
}

With this change the log-file has the answer, how I found the correct \DeclareMathSymbol command.
Another suggestion also from another answer to the already linked question would be to switch to LuaLaTeX and use an unicode math font, that supports \vBar, e.g.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range={\vBar}]{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$\vBar$
\end{document}



Thank you for your answer. Your proposition works on a test document, but when implementing it in the book I am writing, it doesn't work anymore. I get errors saying 'too many \DeclareMathSymbol' and 'too many alphabets defined' which causes problems everywhere... I feel a bit lost at the moment.

@dicemaster666 This would be another issue and therefore another question (and please, don't forget the MWE). However, it seems you are already mixing too much symbol fonts. Try to reduce them to the really needed. Alternatively switch to LuaLaTeX and use package unicode-math (see among others the corresponding answer in the linked question) instead of code like above. But IMHO reducing the number of fonts used in a single document would be recommended in most cases when such errors occur.

@dicemaster666 Guess: If you already use a lot of symbol fonts, please have a look at them. Maybe one of the already provides a ⫨.

Thank you. I am surprised that there is a limited number of fonts one can use in TeX. Anyway, many thanks for your answer. By the way, what is MWE ?

@dicemaster666 → I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?
